# Fechar app no swift

Tags: ios, swift

estou iniciando em programação swift e minha dúvida é como fazer para fechar a aplicação. Por exemplo, no android, usava o `System.exit(0)` tem algo parecido me swift?

Comment: Esqueça essa abordagem Flávio. Opte por um ecra que faça a aplicação inoperacional e informe o utilizador sobre o que está acontecer. Mesmo no Android, em termos de usabilidade para o utilizador, não devia-se realizar essa operação.

Comment: obrigado DaSilva pela resposta. Sim estou removendo essa opção já do desenvolvimento do app.

Answer (score 4):

Há diversas maneiras de terminar a aplicação em Swift, por exemplo: `exit(0)`, `abort()`, `assert(false)`

No entanto, isso vai contra as [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html) da Apple e fará com que o app será rejeitado na App Store. Não existe nenhuma API indicada para terminar uma aplicação iOS. O usuário é quem decide quando fechar o app. Use este método apenas durante o desenvolvimento ou para debugging.

Comment: obrigado Rafael pela dica sobre vou seguir para não ser rejeitado na App Store